# simulated covariance matrix in rtmvnorm() R produces NAs when using Gibbs sampling

Tags: r, matrix, covariance, na

I am constructing a covariance matrix, that I want to use to simulate random values from a multivariate truncated normal distribution using the `rtmvnorm()` function from `tmvtnorm` package in R. The values here are truncated between 1.0 and 10.0.

So far I have managed to construct a covariance matrix that is symmetric and is later coerced to be positive definite in case it was not at first. However, when I'm using the `rtmvnorm()` function with my cov matrix ('sigma') I cannot use Gibbs sampling as this produces NAs.

After some trial-error I've uncovered that this problem only occurs if I use a cov matrix with cor.sd = 1 as input that was coerced to be positive definite by using:

```
#function to create cov-var matrix sigma, where sd of correlations between distributions can be either 0 or 1.   
sig <- function(cor.mean, cor.sd, n, s2T){ 
if (cor.sd == 0){
c <- c(rep(cor.mean, n*n)) #creating correlation vector where correlations are equal
sigma <- matrix(c,n,n)
diag(sigma) <- 1
 }
if (cor.sd > 0){
c <- c(rnorm((n*(n-1))/2, mean = cor.mean, sd = cor.sd)) #creating correlation vector with varying correlations for one halve of matrix
sigma <- diag(n)
sigma[lower.tri(sigma, diag=F)] <- c
sigma <- forceSymmetric(sigma, "L") #creating symmetric cor matrix  
 }
s <- c(rep(sqrt(s2T), n)) #vector with SD for each test
D = diag(s)
sigma = D%*%sigma%*%D   #creating covariance matrix from correlation matrix & sd
return(list(first = as.matrix(sigma), second = c(mean(c), sd(c))))
}

#creating cov-var matrix
sigma <- sig(.7,1,8,1.5)$first    
sigma <- as.matrix(nearPD(sigma)$mat)
  a = c(rep(1.0, 8))
  b = c(rep(10.0, 8))
  mean = rnorm(8, 6.5, 1.5)
  t <- rtmvnorm(10, mean, sigma, lower = a, upper = b, algorithm = "gibbs")
  t
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
  [1,] 5.667528  Inf  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [2,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [3,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [4,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [5,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [6,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [7,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [8,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  [9,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 [10,]      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Alternatively, using rejection sampling in `rtmvnorm()` (this is the default sampling method) I get an acceptable acceptance rate but also an error message saying the following:

```
pmvnorm(lower = a, upper = b, mean = mean, sigma = sigma)
[1] 0.8911258
attr(,"error")
[1] 0.002500692
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Completion with error > abseps"
```

Unfortunately I am not sure what this abseps stands for and whether it would be allright to lower it myself, given that my acceptance rate is quite high. 
Overall, there seems to go something wrong using `rtmvnorm()` with my covariance matrix in which the sd of the correlations between the distributions equals 1. I am trying to find out what goes wrong. Any help on this would be appreciated a lot!